# ¿Cómo actualizar registros por campo de tipo TIME en SQLSERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla que tiene un capo de tipo `DATETIME` de nombre `AppointmentDate` donde guarda datos con formato  `2022-07-27 21:32:54.420`  y otro de tipo `TIME` de nombre `EndHour` y guarda datos con formato `13:00:00.0000000`.

Entonces necesitó una consulta para actualizar los registros donde la fecha sea Menor o Igual a el campo `AppointmenDate` y Mayor al campo `EndHour`.

Implemente este código, pero no me esta funcionando, por que lo que necesitó es que compare contra el campo `AppointmentDate` solo la parte de la fecha y contra el campo `EndHour` solo la hora. (Pense que solo comparar AppointmentDate contra la fecha actual lo haria pero no funciona se debe incluir tambien la comparacion contra EndHour pero no se como hacerlo)

```
UPDATE ScheduledVirtualAppointments SET  IdState = @idStateDone , DateUpdate = GETDATE(), IdUserUpdate = 1
WHERE AppointmentDate < GETDATE() AND 
IdState NOT IN (@idStateDone,@idStateRejection,@idStateCancellation,@idStateQuizAnswers)
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias Patricio Moracho.

El codigo completo quedo asi :

```
    DECLARE @Now DATETIME = 
(SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SWITCHOFFSET(GETDATE(), DATEPART(TZOFFSET, GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time'))))
               
    UPDATE ScheduledVirtualAppointments  SET  IdState = @idStateDone , DateUpdate = GETDATE(), IdUserUpdate = 1 
WHERE CAST(AppointmentDate AS DATE) <= CAST(@Now AS DATE) AND CAST(@Now AS TIME) > EndHour 
AND IdState NOT IN (@idStateDone, @idStateRejection, @idStateCancellation, @idStateQuizAnswers)
```

Answer (score 3):

Según tu pregunta lo que buscas es filtrar en la actualización:

- Por `AppointmentDate` menor o igual al día de hoy
- La hora actual mayor a `EndHour`

Podrías usar `CAST()` para quedarte con cada parte de una fecha/hora:

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME = GETDATE()

UPDATE ScheduledVirtualAppointments 
       SET  IdState = @idStateDone , DateUpdate = GETDATE(), IdUserUpdate = 1
       WHERE CAST(AppointmentDate AS DATE) <= CAST(@Now AS DATE)
             AND CAST(@Now AS TIME) > EndHour
             AND IdState NOT IN (@idStateDone, @idStateRejection, 
                                 @idStateCancellation, @idStateQuizAnswers)
```

Nota: Usamos una variable `@Now` para la fecha actual ya que `GETDATE()` es una función no determinística,  es decir cada ejecución seguramente retorne un valor diferente y como se debe usar más de una vez en la consulta, es preferible manejar siempre la misma fecha/hora.

Comment: Una consulta el reloj de mi pc tiene  28/07/2022  y son las 9:20  AM pero si hago esta consulta 
SELECT GETDATE(), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME) la fecha me aparece bien pero en la hora me aparece 13:20 , entonces creo que falta algo alli  Patricio Moracho

Comment: Pueden ser dos cosas, si el servidor de sql-server está en otro equipo distinto al de tu pc, debería revisar la hora del servidor, el otro problema es que el servidor tenga configurado una zona horaria distinta.

Comment: El problema es que devuelve la Hora UTC... y debo convertirla a la hora Zona horaria -> TimeZone...